# How to call in one line multiple processes in serie

Tags: bash, terminal, script

If I run the following script with 3 lines:

```
process1
process2
process3
```

then `process2` will wait for `process1` to start, and the same will happen with `process3`.

How can I do the same in only one line of a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

If you want to run them one after another:

```
procces1; process2; process3
```

If you want to run the next only if the previous succeded:

```
process1 && process2 && process3
```

If you want to run them simultaneously:

```
process1&; process2&; process3&
```

Comment: The `;`s (semicolons) in the last answer are superfluous; `process1& process2& process3&` is good enough.